# Include external requirejs module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

How can I include/use this require.js module, [PSD.js](https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js), inside my require.js application?

If I use the script like this example below, it works as it should:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/vendor/psd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var PSD = require('psd');

        document.getElementById('dropzone').addEventListener('dragover', onDragOver, true);
        document.getElementById('dropzone').addEventListener('drop', onDrop, true);

        function onDragOver(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
        }

        function onDrop(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();

            PSD.fromEvent(e).then(function (psd) {
                var data = JSON.stringify(psd.tree().export(), undefined, 2);
                document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = data;
                document.getElementById('image').appendChild(psd.image.toPng());
            });
        }
    }());
</script>
```

Here's a live example;
https://jsfiddle.net/numediaweb/8zah99jw/

But if I try to include it by doing the recommanded requirejs way it doesn't;

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'psd': 'vendor/psd.min'
        }
});

// Load our app module 'main.js' and pass it to our definition function
requirejs(['app'], function (App) {
    // The "app" dependency is passed in as "App"
    App.initialize();
});

define('modules/customwidgets.add_widget', [ 'psd'], function () {
    var Widget = function () {
    };
    Widget.prototype = {
        config: {},
        init: function (htmlElement) {
            "use strict";

            // This module
            var me = this;

           console.log('It loads!');

           var PSD = require('psd');

            document.getElementById('dropzone').addEventListener('dragover', onDragOver, true);
            document.getElementById('dropzone').addEventListener('drop', onDrop, true);

            function onDragOver(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
            }

            function onDrop(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();

                PSD.fromEvent(e).then(function (psd) {
                    var data = JSON.stringify(psd.tree().export(), undefined, 2);
                    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = data;
                    document.getElementById('image').appendChild(psd.image.toPng());
                });
            }
        }
    };
    return Widget;
});
```

Comment: What is the `baseurl` config? The browser console should show any module loading failures, and you can probably see the URL it's trying to load in the Network tab.

Comment: I don't have a baseurl as all the scripts are relative to the main.js file where my requirejs.config({}) and also all other modules work so I don't think it has to do with baseurl.

Answer (score 1):

You are still using it in a not recommended way. After define the module, just simply put the name of parameter into the function of that module.

Or if you need to use a library globally like `JQuery`... etc... Use `shim` in requirejs config.

And do not use `var something = require('module_name');` regardless situation.

Here is a quick adjustment:

```js
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'psd': 'vendor/psd.min'
    },
    // export global alias 'PSD' for 'psd.min'
    shim: {
        'psd': {
            'exports': 'PSD'
        }
    }
});

define('modules/customwidgets.add_widget', ['psd'], function () {
    var Widget = function () {
    };
    Widget.prototype = {
        config: {},
        init: function (htmlElement) {
            "use strict";

            // This module
            var me = this;

           console.log('It loads!');

           // This should not be used.
           // var PSD = require('psd'); 

            document.getElementById('dropzone').addEventListener('dragover', onDragOver, true);
            document.getElementById('dropzone').addEventListener('drop', onDrop, true);

            function onDragOver(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
            }

            function onDrop(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();

                PSD.fromEvent(e).then(function (psd) {
                    var data = JSON.stringify(psd.tree().export(), undefined, 2);
                    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = data;
                    document.getElementById('image').appendChild(psd.image.toPng());
                });
            }
        }
    };
    return Widget;
});
```

**Also** this adjustment may not providing 100% percent working code (??). Since you are prototyping `init` method and using `PSD` variable/instance of define block. This `PSD` varibale/instance **may not** available in other place when you are calling `new Widget()`  and/or `new Widget().init()`

Comment: Thanks but the psd is still not recognized by require js; Cannot read property 'fromEvent' of undefined

Comment: @numediaweb, As mentioned in the answer it may not working, because you are **prototyping** `Widget().init()` . This mean you are apply something globally into `Widget` while its content (`PSD`) is only available in certain condition (only inside `define()` block of `'modules/customwidgets.add_widget'` )

Comment: @numediaweb, supposed to be my mistakes when limited the answer into the content you are providing. I will update my answer quickly ;)

Comment: @numediaweb Done! You can check the answer with usage of `shim`

Comment: @LinhPham Do you have a plunkr, a jsbin, or fiddle that shows your solution actually working?

Comment: @Louis, I do not have any, because it is not possible. The information was not enough to create one. Like what is the index.html? what is the view? What is the other piece of code that using `Widget` ? etc...?

Comment: @LinhPham It is quite possible to create a runnable example that loads PSD and uses it. You don't have to replicate *everything* the OP does. Only show that with your solution it loads and is usable.

Comment: The new code gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: PSD is not defined`.

Comment: @numediaweb, Thank you for the fiddle.... And actually I've been working with my `plunkr` for 3 hours straight, tried many workarounds. I am managed to load a small part of PSD, but that is no where near work-able solution. --- The thing we are dealing with is `PSD.js` is completely not cappable to load with `requireJS`. FYI there are serveral ways to wrap `commonJS` package with `requireJS` but except two points which mentioned here https://github.com/jrburke/r.js#convert-commonjs-modules. (and PSD.js matched both of them) --- I am really sorry about this... but this is beyond my ability :-(

Comment: @LinhPham Thanks any way for your time